# Ввод только положительных целых чисел

Tags: java, input, scanner

Как сделать ввод только для целых положительных чисел?

```
private int[] enterNumbers() {
    System.out.print("Enter the number of numbers(n): ");
    while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("This is not a number!");
        in.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        boolean isReady = false;
        int n = 0;
        while(!isReady){
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter the number of numbers(n): ");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                n = scanner.nextInt();
                if(n > 0)
                    isReady = true;
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("wrong number");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(n + "");
```